# AngularJS: Why doesn't the directive see an object on the scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am experimenting with Angular. I have altered [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/77NLB/) for the purpose of this question.

When I try to access the scope variables "password" and "password_confirmation" from the directive, like this it displays them fine. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKS74/3/). Like this:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.passwordAsSeenByDirective = scope['password'] + "...";
          scope.password_confirmationAsSeenByDirective = scope['password_confirmation'] + "...";
        });
```

But when I make an object and put these as properties there, then I cannot access them any more. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE6nS/3/). Like this:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.passwordAsSeenByDirective = scope['obj.password'] + "...";
          scope.password_confirmationAsSeenByDirective = scope['obj.password_confirmation'] + "...";
        });
```

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `scope['obj']['password']`

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both!

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the complete answer, as I am still learning AngularJS myself.  However one bit of help I can impart is that you can't access a variable like scope["foo.bar"].  "foo.bar" is an Angular Expression, not a property syntax and therefore must be either parsed with $parse or evaluated with scope.$eval

Comment: You are welcome.  Care to share a working fiddle so we can both learn more?

Comment: Well Hawk's answer is only good if you want to hard code things.  Its important to understand what is happening under the hood here.  The Angular notation can be expanded to standard notation.  You can do it by hand like hawk suggests, but you are better off doing it dynamically with the proper tools as I mentioned.